# WC add_to_cart adding additional product if already in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

If I add a product to the cart programmatically and then do so once more with the product already in the cart, then it adds an extra one. So instead of two of the product, there are three.

**In functions.php**

```
function add_bonus_product( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {
    
    $productArray = array(52, 78, 93);

    if(in_array($product_id, $productArray)){
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 205, $quantity, 0, array(), array( "parent_product_line_item" => $cart_item_key ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_bonus_product', 13, 6 );
```

Above is a simplified version of my original function. Even when boiled down to this point the problem still occurs.

**For example**, lets say product_id "52" from the function above is a T-shirt. In the function, whenever that product is added, product_id "205" is added as well.

For some reason if the T-shirt is in the cart already (along with product_id "205") and I add another one to the cart, then there are two T-shirts now in the cart but three of product_id "205".

It's adding an extra and I don't know why.

Comment: _"It's adding an extra and I don't know why"_. I cannot reproduce the problem, your code is working as it should. However know that the `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` action hook might be more convenient, 
It depends on what you specifically trying to do. For example, if afterwards the product with ID 52 is removed from the cart (on cart page), what should happen with the product with ID 205, can it just stay in the cart or should it be also (automatically) removed?

Comment: In the add_to_cart function i set the cart item data of parent_product_line_item to the original product's cart item key. I have separate functions that utilize that to add and remove product_id "205" based on product_is "52". Interesting its working fine for you though.